# Restrict Storage Admins from specific GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-iam

Can I restrict users/service accounts with roles/storageAdmin permission from a specific GCS Bucket?

I have a sensitive bucket that should be writeable only from a specific service account, and restrict write permissions from all other accounts, even from storage admins.

I've tried setting the permissions to `unified` instead of `acl`, with the following iam set on the bucket:

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:my-sa@my-account.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.objectAdmin"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "group:my-dev-team@my-company.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.objectViewer"
    }
  ],
  "etag": "abcd"
}
```

Some of my team members have the `roles/storageAdmin` role, and they can also write to the bucket - which I need to restrict.

Comment: None of the strategies will work except for CMEK encryption. The Owner of an account can simply change the permissions to grant access. If I am the owner of a Google Cloud Project, there is nothing you can do to prevent me from reading the data in a bucket in the same project except to slow me down by five minutes. The exception would be to implement CMEK (Customer Managed Encryption Keys) and encrypt the data. You could create a new project, create a bucket in that project and then grant access to IAM members of the other project. However, the owner of the new project can still access data.

Comment: @JohnHanley I don't mind if the owner changes his permissions, I just want to make sure that he won't be able to write / overwrite the data by accident. As far as I understand from your answer Storage Admin is more powerful than the specific IAM roles for the bucket. Am I correct?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. The role **roles/storage.admin** has full control of buckets and objects within a project when attached to an identity at the project level. In that case, you cannot limit the scope except via Organizational Policies (constraints). https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/org-policy-constraints The existing constraints will not help your objective.

Answer (score 0):

At the bucket level, there is [uniform bucket-level access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access), [Identity and Access Management](https://cloud.google.com/iam) (IAM) and [Access Control List](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#default) (ACL). If you want to avoid creating GCP accounts for the users, then try Access Control List (ACL).

If you want to regulate the access each user has within the bucket, you should try Access Control List (ACL).

An [access control list](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#default) (ACL) is a mechanism you can use to define who has access to your buckets and objects, and what level of access they have. In Cloud Storage, you apply ACLs to individual buckets and objects. Each ACL consists of one or more entries. An entry gives a specific user (or group) the ability to perform specific actions. Each entry consists of two pieces of information:
A permission, which defines what actions can be performed (for example, read or write).
A scope (sometimes referred to as a grantee), which defines who can perform the specified actions (for example, a specific user or group of users).

Here is a list of the accesses that can be granted:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know if a user with roles/storageAdmin will be able to write objects to the bucket with ACL that permit only specific service account?

Comment: Here is what I found about  the rore: Grants full control of buckets and objects.
When applied to an individual bucket, control applies only to the specified bucket and objects within the bucket.

Comment: I found this article that can be useful: https://tsmx.net/accessing-a-single-bucket-in-gcs/

Comment: The article really helped, I'll add the condition to the specific storage admins the should not write data to the buckets. Thank you